# Are operators that commute with decomposable operators also decomposable?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $T \in B(H)$ be a decomposable operator $\int_X T_x d\mu(x)$ where $T_x \in B(H_x)$ and $(X,\mu)$ is some measure space. Now, suppose that $S$ commutes with $T$. Can we conclude that $S$ is also decomposable? That is, there exists a measurable field of operators $S_x \in B(H_x)$ such that $S = \int_X S_x d\mu(x)$? If not, are there some extra conditions that we can place on $T$ so that it is true?

I believe if $T$ and $S$ are both normal then it will be true since they generate an abelian von Neumann algebra and so they will be simultaneously diagonablisable. However, I am not sure if the above is still true in the general case.

It would be appreciated if anyone could point me to any relevant references.

Answer (score 1):

Take this answer as coming from someone who is deadly afraid of direct integrals.

In spirit, the operator $T$ is "block diagonal". The problem with commutants of diagonal matrices is multiplicity. In finite dimension you can have the operator
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The double multiplicity of $1$ makes the commutant of $T$ to be $M_2(\mathbb C)\oplus\mathbb C$. In a direct integral you may have the same problem. If there is a measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$ and $T_x=T_y$ for all $x,y\in E$, then the commutant of $T$ will include "full-matrices" for the entries indexed by $E$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is a good point. Do you know (or anyone else) if that is the only obstruction for $S$ being decomposable? I.e. if $\{T_x\}$ are pair-wise distinct almost everywhere, then will $S$ be decomposable?

Comment: Another obstruction is that there could be a different decomposition than the one you have in mind.  Consider $T_1 = \pmatrix{a & 0\cr 0 & b}$, $T_2 = \pmatrix{b & 0\cr 0 & a\cr}$ as decomposition of $T = \pmatrix{a & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & b & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & b & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & a}$.  These are not the same, and $T$ commutes with matrices such as $\pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$ that don't have this decomposition.